# How can I make the .git folder not disappear in the build folder after npm run build?

Tags: reactjs, git

I have a React app and I want to make the build folder its own Git repository, but every time I run `npm run build`, the .git folder inside the regenerated /build directory disappears. How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 2):

I think you can use `postbuild` command in script in your `package.json`, which will run immediately after build. It will run automaticaly.

Example:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "postbuild": "copy .git .\\build\\.git"
},
```

Comment: Wouldn't this simply copy the parent's git folder to the build/.git path? That's not what I want.

Comment: Khm, got it!
So in this case it could be a `prebuild` script in pair with `postbuild` and i think it's only one way - on prebuild copy `.git` to `temp build folder` and then, in `postbuild` copy it to your new `build` folder. Cause each new build we have totally new `build`.
Somethinkg like this:
`"scripts": {
    "prebuild":  "mkdir -p temp_build && copy .\\build\\.git .\\temp_build\\.git "
    "postbuild": "copy \\temp_build\\.git .\\build\\.git && rm -rf temp_build"
},`

P.S. I'm not a guru of bash, but it could be a trooth. Hope it could help you!

Answer (score -2):

In your package.json, change the build script to this:

```
"scripts": {
    [...]
    "build": "rm -rf build_old/.git && cp -R build/.git build_old/.git && react-scripts build && cp -R build_old/.git build/.git"
}
```

It does the following:

1. Deletes the build_old/.git folder (make sure to create the build_old folder first).
2. Copies your original .git folder to the build_old directory.
3. Runs `react-scripts build`.
4. Pastes the .git directory back.